# Define a new Projection for display WFS layers

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3, projection, geoserver

I´m new in OpenLayers 3. I´m working with GeoServer 2.6.1 and I would like to create a web mapping with OpenLayers 3.

I have a problem with the projection: it is not defined in Proj4js library or epsg.io web. **It is not an EPSG projection.** I can display WMS layers correctly because GeoServer´s transformation is good, but I have not been able to display WFS layers because of being a not defining projection at any library.

I have consulted a lot of example codes, but I have not found the solution. May you please help me define a new coordinate system and implement it in my code JavaScript?